# How to reassign Ref objects in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to fix part of a project where I do not have control over how they are using refs. Currently there are Editable text elements that are being controlled by using refs and a state varible in the component holding all of these refs. I am trying to implement a cancel button which resets the edited fields to their orginal default value.

I have tried using the blow code to accomplish this by replacing, the edited value which seems to be stored in ref.state.value with the original value, stored in ref.props.defaultValue

this.state.refs is defined as

```
refs: Array<EditableText | null>;
```

editable text: https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/editable-text

Editable Text components with refs:

```
<EditableText
   disabled={!this.state.editingDesc}
   multiline={true}
   maxLines={10}
   defaultValue={description}
   ref={input =>
     (this.state.refs[index + 1] = input)
   }
/>
```

Function with error

```
public handleCancelBtn = () => {
    const newRefs = this.state.refs.map(ref => {
      if (ref != null) {
        const originalValue = ref.props.defaultValue;
        const newState = { ...ref.state, value: originalValue };
        const newRef = { ...ref, state: newState };
        return newRef;
      }
      return null;
    });
    this.setState({
      editingDesc: false,
      refs: newRefs
    });
  };
```

The problem is that the compilier is saying that I can't assign newRefs to ref since I am missing properties to make them an edited text element, such as render, componentDidMount etc. I am not understanding why the spread operator is not taking care of copying everything from the original ref. I do not know much about refs though and cannot find much relevant documentation for this use case. I do wish I could refactor this whole component to use state instead, sadly I will have to wait on that. If anyone could give me some help, I will be very appreciative. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `Object.assign()` method copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object.
Give a look to [Object.assign documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [Object.assign vs Object Spread](https://thecodebarbarian.com/object-assign-vs-object-spread.html)

**edited**

```
public handleCancelBtn = () => {
    const newRefs = this.state.refs.map(ref => {
      if (ref != null) {
        let newRef = Object.assign({}, ref);
        newRef.state.value = ref.props.defaultValue;
        return newRef;
      }
      return null;
    });

    this.setState({
      editingDesc: false,
      refs: newRefs
    });
  };
```

Comment: It is still giving me the same error. The object.assign gives me the correct type of (EditableText | Null)[], but the problem still remains where the compiler tells me that newRefs is missing valueElement, refHandlers, render etc. Thank you for your reply though

Comment: @C.Programming when creating the newRefs try to replace the `ObjectSpread` by `Object.assign`

Comment: Object.assign seems to be giving me the union of Editable text and state: {...} which equates to ref.state. I want to replace the Ref.state with this state: {...} instead.

Comment: I changed my spread operator for newRef assignment to const newRef = Object.assign({}, ref, {state: newState});

Comment: @C.Programming any progress? what if you copy the original object and then go to the property and set the new value? I have edited my answer.

Comment: You can't assign newRef.state.value like that since it is a constant. That is why I was trying to create a new object with that value and reassign the ref

Comment: @C.Programming sorry I didn't know value was a constant. I understand what you mean. do you have any progress?